# como fazer um pop up que abra na mesma janela

Tags: php, html, popup

Gostaria de saber como fazer um pop up que abra na mesma janela após o usuário clicar em um botão na página. O conteúdo do pop up ficaria em uma página separada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use o `window.open`:

```
<button onclick="window.open('pagina.html','_blank','width=400, height=300')">Abrir popup</button>
```

> É importante saber que a *popup* só irá funcionar mediante evento de
> *click* por parte do usuário, caso contrário o navegador bloqueará por padrão.

Sintaxe do `window.open`:

```
window.open(URL, nome, propriedades, replace)
```

Informações detalhadas você pode conferir no **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)**.

### Edit

Abrir uma *popup* via `iframe`:

```js
function abrirPopUp(){
   var pagina = "pagina.html";
   var popup = document.querySelector("iframe");
   popup.src = pagina;
   popup.style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
iframe{
   -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
   -moz-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   position: fixed;
   display: none;
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 99;
   width: 500px;
   height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="abrirPopUp()">Abrir popup</button>
<iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: o window.open abre um nova janela, queria que o popup ficasse na mesma  janela em que foi dado o click.

Comment: @Ehren999 Boa noite!! Entendi agora o que vc queria. Quer abrir como se fosse uma modal. Vou reformular a resposta, vc aguarda alguns minutos?

Comment: claro, obrigado!

Comment: @Ehren999 Adicionei na resposta uma opção via iframe.

Comment: muito obrigado!